# A question about the feasibility of the Casimir propulsion system

Tags: propulsion, design-alternative, advanced-propulsion, vacuum

There is a connection between vacuum energy density and the Casimir effect , see :

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0204125

Another reference can be found here:

https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.16749

The Casimir vacuum between parallel plates has a lower  energy density than the vacuum outside the plates. That's what puts the plates in (attractive ) motion in the original Casimir experiment.

Based on these references (and many others) in vacuum,  in the absence of any other forces or fields,  it seems that matter tends to follow the gradient of the vacuum energy density  (  for example  from high vacuum energy density  to low vacuum energy density )?

**Question**.  In vacuum,  in the absence of any other forces,  a ship with a large number of Casimir plates at one end , will it tend to move **without the need of any fuel** (as slow as it may)? This asymmetric "pressure" phenomenon would be caused by the gradient of vacuum energy density.

A picture's worth a thousand words. The design can be seen here:

https://www.academia.edu/40406366/Design_Test

In this design the Casimir plates are parallel to the direction of travel. The ship moves for the same reason the plates are pushed together in the original Casimir experiment,  following the gradient of the vacuum energy density.

If you want to see some feedback from physics:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503796/31339

If this design is not feasible , please explain.  If it is feasible, is anyone interested in testing it (this is not garage work)?

Comment: As you will see from the comments over on physics.SE this is still so theoretical it's not really going to be on topic here.

Comment: There are active or retired rocket scientists, NASA  engineers  , and other specialists,  active on  this domain. Thie feasibility problem is a problem of engineering.  There is no better site on stackexchange for this question. If feasible,  interstellar travel would become a real possibility.  If feasible.

Comment: In other words, if this design is feasible,  then multigenerational space travel would become a REAL possibility.

Comment: It's not yet even at feasibility - the basic premise has more questions than answers. If it is possible to scale it, then it would become much more useful here - I think physics is the correct place. You asked "will it tend to move without fuel" - and literally everything we know says "no"

Comment: You have to read carefully the accepted answer on physics.SE, coming from a physicist.  The answer to the question "will it tend to move without fuel " is definitely not a clear no. It just requires the attention of experts, in order to reach a definite answer.

Comment: Please read the other answers there - I would give some of them more weight than the one you accepted. Remember, like your earlier question on changing gravity, sci-fi is not really on topic here. And this is still sci-fi at the moment (will be great if it becomes just sci)

Comment: I am not a physicist,  as I clearly state in my profile (I am a mathematician), , but I don't lack creativity and imagination .  The accepted answer on physics.SE comes from a person who knows what she's talking about. The other answers , as you can see if you really read them, come from amateurs and enthusiasts.  Granted,  in the accepted answer, she is very cautious,  she just emphasizes the need for a closer analysis and testing. That's all I am saying here, there's something interesting in this design,  based on the Casimir effect.  It doesn't go against any law of physics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98972/discussion-between-rory-alsop-and-cristian-dumitrescu).

Comment: Sorry   I tried that before,  I am using a smartphone and I get lost in all the threads there, the user interface  confuses me. If you want to continue this conversation,  you have my email on my profile.  Look, I'll be honest and direct. If you boys don't like my design,  delete my question from your site. I'm not in it for any personal gain, I would write a paper about it or seek a patent for my design if that was the case.  But if you find interstellar travel as fascinating as I do, you will at least settle the question that I asked. And that can only be done by experts.

Comment: Or you could cite a scholarly work explaining a particular implementation, and ask how well it could be fit into a spacecraft considering typical spacecraft-design principles.

Comment: There are hundreds of papers about the Casimir effect available on the net. One relevant paper is mentioned in my question  https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0204125  As for the design , that's my work, as new as it gets, you are the first to hear about it,  and the people from physics.SE. There are no other sources.  I just hoped  the engineers  and scientists  active on this site will take this seriously.

Comment: The Casimir effect is a well established fact in physics.  The mathematics behind this effect tells us that matter does tend to follow the gradient of vacuum energy density.  When I said "would it work" in my question,  I was referring to the design itself,  the Casimir effect  is not under question.  So this is a problem of application of a physical phenomenon,  this is a practical problem.  @uhoh

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu I've added the `design-alternative` tag which will apply even with an edit. The paper is about the Casimir effect, but not about *a propulsive effect based on the Casimir effect in space*. Stack Exchange has a fairly limited scope and questions should strive to be answerable. Posting a question should not be used to *induce people to take designs seriously*, they should be written to generate specific answers that can be evaluated as "right" or "wrong". If you can't formulate your question in that way, then Stack Exchange is not the right place for your question.

Comment: Thank you  @uhoh  My question also allows a binary answer (right/wrong , correct/incorrect). It just requires more work than the average question here.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu Okay you've convinced me! I have **retracted my close vote** and posted an answer.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as posted on physics stack exchange.

Comment: Cross-posting is not allowed. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 5):

The method described proposes a propulsive force based on

> following the gradient of the vacuum energy density.

However, I see two problems

1. There is no evidence given in the question showing that a gradient in vacuum energy exists.
2. Even if one did exist (some location has a lower vacuum energy than another location) there is no evidence given in the question showing that the energy density between the Casimir plates would not similarly decrease *by the same amount*, for the same reason.

In order for this to be feasible, you will have to demonstrate that gradients exist in the **difference vacuum energy density** between the outside and the inside of the plates.

So far I don't see any evidence provided for that difference, so as proposed, I don't see how there would be a propulsive force.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47922/31339 You can also do a search on the net with keywords "energy density Casimir effect". There are quite a lot of papers written by specialists treating this subject. You really need to know something about the subject before you write an answer. @uhoh

Comment: The results related to the Casimir effect and the existence of the gradient of vacuum energy density, these are established facts. The reference list is too long for a comment, do a search yourself. The only question is whether my design is feasible  or not.  I already said that in comments.

Comment: "do a search yourself" is not how Stack Exchange works. Can you add one or two specific examples of existence of the gradient of vacuum energy density to your question, along with specific examples of the gradient of the *inside/outside difference*? If your question is based on premises then you need to clearly support those premises yourself. Just say they exist and it's the answer author's responsibility to go look them up for you doesn't work in Stack Exchange.

Comment: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/casimir.html

Comment: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Energy-density-in-the-Casimir-effect-Sopova-Ford/4caadca580a82e76c00875333b4f622866a9cba6

Comment: And many, many more, I won't bother.  You boys didn't like this. Bummer,  that's OK.. This was not a crank question.  Good luck with your trivia debates, and the mass of paint problem in rocket design.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu what makes the Stack Exchange [ecosystem](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) work so well as a public site is it's rigid adherence to structured questions and answers. It's not a discussion forum, and isn't really a good place to vet new ideas or concepts. That does happen sometimes, but in those cases people carefully support their premises when asking, or respond in a positive way to requests by *editing their question* and incorporating requested premise support or other modifications *within the question itself.*

Comment: I understand this isn't a crank question, that's why I engaged in a series of helpful comments and posted an answer, and retracted my close vote. But in order to get something out of this site, it's necessary to invest some work and try to fit your question into the SE way of doing things. Have another look around here, in Physics SE or elsewhere and see how people formulate their questions and work with commenters to try to fit in to the site's structure.

Comment: Thanks @uhoh I edited my question, I added one more reference. At the end of the day, I could be wrong, and this could be a waste of time, but this is not obviously clear at this point . The calculations (similar to those given in the first two references in my question) must be performed for the design configuration that I describe. This is QFT mathematics,  I am only superficially familiar with it. Only then a definite answer to my question can be given. Dismissing my question from start just because the mathematics behind it is hard, I consider that a mistake, if progress has meaning here.

Comment: https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0217732318501407

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.02414

Comment: The two references above discuss a derivation of the Casimir effect based on the uncertainty principle. Consider now a three connected, rectangular plate configuration, with two parallel plates and a connecting orthogonal plate at one end. In principle you can think of a U-bracket, but the distance between the parallel plates has to be very, very small, like in the original Casimir experiment. Follow the method described in the two references in the two comments above. You will find that there is a Casimir force with direction parallel to the parallel plates  @uhoh

Comment: Please read the three comments above @RoryAlsop  I think the existence of the Casimir force described can be proved theoretically . The engineerical problem is a problem of magnitude,  feasibility,  and design optimization.

Comment: And you don't have to be an expert in QFT (neither am I) , in order to follow this argument. I know it's counterintuitive,  but so is the existence of the Casimir force between two parallel plates, as in the original Casimir experiment (and that's an established fact in physics, and measured). I am simply trying to use an asymmetric Casimir configuration,  in order to use the emerging Casimir force for propulsion.

Comment: My last few comments provide the evidence that you requested @uhoh